# How to configure the expire date of orbeon resources

Tags: date, orbeon, xforms

We have Orbeon 3.8 PE

According to the documentation, "At the moment, the resources served by the PFC (that is all the resources except the XForms engine's CSS and JavaScript resources) do not automatically get a special expiration date. "

We have seen that the expire date is established 15 days since the day and time it is downloaded. The browser doesn't ask for that component until 15 days have passed.

We want to increase the amount of days.

How can this be done ? What jar or class must I modify?

We don't want to use apache expire filter

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the documentation is incorrect, as I see that the code uses the standard HTTP heuristic of the "age of the resource plus 10%".

The relevant source code is in [ResourceServer.java](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/java/org/orbeon/oxf/processor/ResourceServer.java), [XFormsResourceServer.java](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/processor/XFormsResourceServer.java), and [ServletExternalContext.java](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/java/org/orbeon/oxf/servlet/ServletExternalContext.java#L442).

Note that with versioned resources (available in the PE version), resource URLs include a version number and are aggressively cached, so that in effect they "never" expire from the browser (of course the browser can still expire them any time it wants based on cache settings).

**Update:** Actually the documentation was more imprecise than incorrect: what it meant to say was that, even with versioned resources enabled, resources served by the PFC did not get an expiration date set far in the future.

However since October 2011 builds, this has been fixed, and versioned resources served by the PFC do expire far in the future. Now *without* versioned resources, neither resources served by the PFC nor those served by the XForms engine have an expiration set far in the future. In that case, they do follow the "age of the resource plus 10%" heuristic. This means that if you are not using versioned resources, you have to either modify the source code of Orbeon Forms (which to be fair we do not recommend in this specific case), or use a filter or an Apache front-end.